# Can't get Netflix add-in for Windows 7 Media Center to appear

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

Recently Netflix released their Windows 7 Media Center add-on to enable instant streaming. On one of my Windows 7 machines I triggered a manual download, and that installed the Netflix add-on just fine> However, on my other machine I can't get the add-in to appear. I've done a manual update multiple times, but it never shows up. Any idea on how I can get it to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I used to fix the problem:

1. Open Control Panel/Programs and Features.
2. Click "Turn Windows features on or off" in the left pane.
3. Expand "Media Features", uncheck "Windows Media Center". Click "Yes" to continue, and click OK to quit. Then Restart.
4. Open "Turn Windows features on or off" again. Turn on the features "Windows Media Player" and "Windows Media Center". Restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turned out my Media Center wasn't configured for automatic updates. When I enabled it (go to Automatic Download options and click "Download now" as [described here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/972496) the updates were downloaded and the netflix menu has appeared.

Comment: Triggering the manual download has the same effect, but it didn't fix it in my case.